# function containing arrange() does not work in R

Tags: r, function

I was experimenting with functions based on Hadley Wickham's R for Data Science (2e) book, chapter 25. (https://r4ds.hadley.nz/functions) but cannot get the unique_where function described in 25.3.3 working.
This is the function:

```
library(tidyverse)

unique_where <- function(df, condition, var) {
  df |>
    filter({{ condition }}) |>
    distinct({{ var }}) |>
    arrange({{ var }})
}
```

```
data(flights, package = "nycflights13")

flights |> unique_where(month == 12, dest)
```

always returns an error: object 'dest' not found

The problem is caused by the arrange() step. The function without that step works fine.

Outside of a function, the commands work fine:

```
flights |> filter(month == 12 ) |> distinct(dest) |> arrange(dest)
```

returns the expected output.

Why does the arrange() step not work?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. What version of R, dplyr and nycflights13 are you using?

Comment: Works with me, I'm voting to close as not reproducible. Have you tried ending and restarting your R session? And check if you have a file named `.RData` in your working directory. If you do, try to delete it and restart R.

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce any problem: for me, the data is filtered, distinct'ed, and arranged as expected, into a 96-row 1-column tibble.